# Rails 3: Call functions inside controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I want to have functions to be called inside controllers, where should I put them?

Comment: Please give more info, do you want it to be available to all controllers?

Comment: @ddayan, yes to all controllers but I'd be happy to know how to limit to one controller.

Comment: @jonnii, for example, I want to call a function that returns a generated unique code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you want it to be local to a controller then all you need to do is to add it to the controller you wish to use.

```
private
def myfunction
  function code.....
end
```

to all controllers you can put it inside the application controller, because all controlers are sub classed.

## ApplicationController

```
protected

def myfunction

  function code.....

end
```

If you want access in your views then you can create a helper

## ApplicationHelper

```
def myfunction

  function code...

end
```

Comment: I believe the `ApplicationController` example should be protected, not private.

Comment: true. Forgot to change it when I copy & pasted it from the first example. thanks for spotting it out.

Answer (score 4):

> @jonnii, for example, I want to call a function that returns a generated unique code.

If your generated code is going to be used only on your *controllers*, put the function inside a controller, as protected function (the easiest way would be putting it inside ApplicationController).

If you need to call the function on the *views*, then put it on a helper, like ddayan says.

If you also need to invoke the function from *models*, then the simplest way to do it is by putting a module inside the /lib/ directory.

```
# /lib/my_module.rb
module MyModule
  def generate_code
    1
  end
end
```

You will also need to include it with an initializer:

```
#/config/initializers/my_module.rb
require 'my_module'
```

From that moment on, you can use the function like this:

```
MyModule::generate_code
```

If you are doing this very often, consider creating a gem.

Answer (score 3):

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base

  def your_action
    your_function
  end

  private

    def your_function

    end
end
```

Also look at `before_filter` and `after_filter`, they're often useful in such kind of things

Answer (score 0):

The ApplicationController is here for that, since every Controller inherited from it.