# Call inner controller actions and send params between them rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an API and I want that the outside can only has access to update method to actualize a report. But in case there is no report I want to create it. I know that the easy way to do it is just create it inside update method, but as soon I have already a create method build I was wondering if is it possible to call it sending it also some params.

I looked around like here [Rails 3: Call functions inside controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605837/rails-3-call-functions-inside-controllers) or the API but I didn't found any good solution.

Does anyone has a better one?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: no, you should delegate this creation process to the update action. An action in a Controller is made to respond to a request, I don't think you can call it from anywhere like this. But you could have a protected method in your controller that would create the Report if it does not exist.

Comment: Ok. So I should do something like this: "private/ def create_report(params).....end / and then (from action) def myaction ... report=create_report(myparams) ... end

Comment: MrYoshiji you are a well of wisdom. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call an action of your controller from another action.

**Why?** Because every action of a controller is defined to respond to a request, which has several attributes (such as IP, params, session, HTTP headers, etc.). Imagine how "weird" it would be to call an action from another in the Controller.

If you want to do "extra logic" which would not be related to the update action (for example, create), you should call a protected (accessible only via the Controller & its children) method of this controller.

**In your case**, you could do something like this:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @report = Report.where(id: params[:report_id]).first
    if @report.nil?
      create_report(params)
    else
      # etc.
    end
  end

  protected

  def create_report(params)
    Report.create(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks master! I really appreciate your time and efforts.